# ar cannot create archive: "File format not recognized"

Tags: c++, unix-ar

I have this makefile

```
libjackpot.a: jackport.o jackpot.o
    ar -rcs jackport.o jackpot.o

jackpot.o: jackpot.cpp jackpot.h
    g++ jackpot.cpp -std=c++11 -O2 -c

jackport.o: jackport.cpp jackpot.h jackport.h
    g++ jackport.cpp -std=c++11 -O2 -c
```

Somehow (on my Linux box), I get

```
ar: jackport.o: File format not recognized
```

ar --help gives

```
ar: supported targets: elf64-x86-64 elf32-i386 elf32-x86-64 a.out-i386-linux pei-i386 pei-x86-64 elf64-l1om elf64-k1om elf64-little elf64-big elf32-little elf32-big plugin srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex
```

file jackport.o

```
jackport.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to specify the library name for ar, e.g.:

```
   ar -rcs libjackpot.a jackport.o jackpot.o
```

Comment: How could I miss that

Answer (score 1):

Yes, archive name is missing. You also have access to the target name. In your case "libjackpot.a" with a variable "$@".

```
libjackpot.a: jackport.o jackpot.o
    ar -rcs $@ jackport.o jackpot.o
```

One step further, "$^" is the prerequisite list

```
libjackpot.a: jackport.o jackpot.o
    ar -rcs $@ $^
```